# Error: "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey" appears only on CupertinoScaffolds

Tags: flutter

When I use cupertino scaffolds with GlobalKey it gives this error:

> Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

Key:

GlobalKey loginFormkey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "loginkey");

But on material scaffold it works fine.

Does anybody know why it doesn't work on cupertino scaffolds ?

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will produce the issue?

Comment: Can you share more context of _where in your code_ you are *creating* the `GlobalKey`? And also, share where you are *using* it? As Yeasin mentioned, a code snippet would be best.